# Changing AUTOLOAD in the symbol table in perl

Tags: perl

General context: I am trying to encapsulate [Geo::Geos](https://metacpan.org/dist/Geo-Geos/view/lib/Geo/Geos.pod) and its underlying classes to make its API more perl-ish.

in doing so I'm trying to create an AUTOLOAD method that will catch the encapsulating class's method calls, and map them to `Geo::Geos` calls.

For example:

```
$polygon->getArea;
```

maps to

```
$polygon->area;
```

with the plan later to simplify calls, make them chainable etc.

To do that I have a function like this:

```
sub superautoload {
    my $self = shift;
    my $ref = (ref $self || $self) =~ s/::Simple//r;

    no strict "refs";
    my $al = ${$ref . "::AUTOLOAD"}  =~ s/.+:://r;

    if (my $sub = $self->can("get" . camelize($al))) {
        return $sub->($self, @_)
    }
    elsif ($sub = $self->can(lcfirst camelize($al))) {
        return $sub->($self, @_)
    }
}
```

and I'm trying - for a subset of Geo::Geos's object types - to inject something like so:

```
*{($classname  =~ s/::Simple//r) . "::AUTOLOAD"} = sub { return superautoload(@_) };
```

which causes failures, "Use of uninitialized value" warings, the lot.

In desperation I tried this hack:

```
eval (sprintf 'sub %s::AUTOLOAD { return superautoload(@_) }', $classname =~ s/::Simple//r);
```

and things works exactly the way I aimed for.

Why? How do I avoid `eval`, which is supposed to be not-ok? How do I inject asub into a symbol table?

Comment: Which var is "unintialized"? Please provide the code that results in the error. You need to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Tip: `sub { return superautoload(@_) }` is an expensive version of `\&superautoload`.

Comment: Tip: The autoloader should create the sub so to avoid having to do the same work again later.

Comment: @ikegami - thanks. In searching for an answer to your "Which var..." question, I found out my  ```my $al = ${$ref . "::AUTOLOAD"}  =~ s/.+:://r;```line is a monstruosity. Changing to ```our $AUTOLOAD;``` solves the problem.

Comment: @ikegami Could you please expand just a little on your tip ("autoloader should create the sub"), which sounds very cool and interesting?

Comment: Replace `return $sub->($self, @_);` with something like `*$name = $sub; goto &$name;` (and leave `$self` in `@_`).

Comment: I have an example of ikegami's comment in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I might approach this problem. You don't need to work so hard in `AUTOLOAD`.

Some notes:

- You don't need to worry about methods that already exist, because you shouldn't be in `AUTOLOAD` in that case.
- Maybe you have a reason for wanting to assign a sub to `AUTOLOAD`, but I'd just define `AUTOLOAD` directly. You can inherit `AUTOLOAD` too.

So here's an example, where most of the work is just string manipulations to translate the fully-qualified method name in `$AUTOLOAD` to the target method name. The result of `can` is either a subroutine reference if the method exists somewhere in the inheritance chain (or something wants you to think it does with their own `can` definition) or undef if it doesn't:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.10;

package Foo {
    use Carp;
    sub AUTOLOAD {
        my( $thing, @args ) = @_;
        say "Caught $AUTOLOAD";

        my $method = $AUTOLOAD =~ s/.*:://r;
        say "Target method is $method";

        # however you need to translate this:
        $method = lc($method);
        my $mapped_method = $method =~ s/\Aget//r;
        say "Target method is $mapped_method";

        my $sub_ref = $thing->can($mapped_method);

        Carp::croak( "Unknown method $mapped_method from $method" )
            unless defined $sub_ref;

        no strict 'refs';
        *{$AUTOLOAD} = $sub_ref; # what ikegami was telling you to do

        # call the sub with leading & to reuse @_ and pretend
        # we weren't here. Or just $sub_ref->(@_) if you don't
        # care
        &$sub_ref;
        }

    sub area {
        say "In area";
        }
    }

package Bar {
    our @ISA = qw(Foo);
    }

Foo->getArea;
Foo->getArea;
Bar->getArea;
```

The output shows that `AUTOLOAD` installs the `area` method the first time around, and subsequent calls in to `area` in the parent or child classes go directly to the new definition:

```
Caught Foo::getArea
Target method is getArea
Target method is area
In area
In area
In area
```

But there's an issue here, and one I'm not particularly inclined to solve for this answer. That `AUTOLOAD` installed the new definition in `Foo` because I called `Foo` first. Try it with `Bar` first:

```
Bar->getArea;
Foo->getArea;
Foo->getArea;
Bar->getArea;
```

Now the output shows that `AUTOLOAD` jumps in twice. The first time it installed the new `getArea` in `Bar`, but since `Foo` does not know about `Bar`'s methods, calling `getArea` on `Foo` again goes through the same process:

```
Caught Bar::getArea
Target method is getArea
Target method is area
In area
Caught Foo::getArea
Target method is getArea
Target method is area
In area
In area
In area
```

And it gets a bit weirder. Suppose there is a third class that defines its own `area`. I already have a definition for `getArea` in `Foo` that points to `Foo`'s `area` method. The child class doesn't get a chance to `AUTOLOAD` a method that is already defined:

```
...
package Quux {
    our @ISA = qw(Bar);
    sub area { say "In quux area" }
    }

Foo->getArea;
Foo->getArea;
Bar->getArea;
Quux->getArea;
```

Now `Quux::area` is shadowed:

```
Caught Foo::getArea
Target method is getArea
Target method is area
In area
In area
In area
In area   <-- should have called Quux::area
```

There's a lot of bookkeeping that you can do to get around that and I'm just going to leave that there.

### An alternate solution

`AUTOLOAD` is nice when I have a low probability of having to use its magic. If I know that I'm going to use those functions, I can do that work ahead of time (trading some startup time for later speed):

```
package Foo {
    sub area { say "In area"; }
    *{'getArea'} = \&area;
    }

Foo->getArea;
```

But, I don't want type that out for every method, so I can handle it for all the methods at the end of the package definition with a `BEGIN`. This does mostly the same work as `AUTOLOAD`, just ahead time for every defined sub:

```
use v5.10;

package Foo {
    sub area { say "In area"; }
    sub length { say "In length"; }

    BEGIN {
        no strict 'refs';
        foreach my $name ( keys %{__PACKAGE__ . '::'} ) {
            next unless defined &$name;
            my $new_name = 'get' . ucfirst($name);
            *{$new_name} = \&$name;
            }
        }
    }

Foo->getArea;
Foo->getLength;
```

The output shows that I can call both of the `get` names:

```
In area
In length
```

That's a bit annoying because other definitions get caught up in this mess. We tend to be fast and loose with imports and what should actually be a method and what should be private. In this example, I import `Carp` but don't really intend it to be a method. However, it is a defined sub in `Foo`, so the `BEGIN` indiscriminately includes it:

```
use v5.10;

package Foo {
    use Carp qw(croak);
    sub area { say "In area"; }
    sub length { say "In length"; }

    BEGIN {
        no strict 'refs';
        foreach my $name ( keys %{__PACKAGE__ . '::'} ) {
            next unless defined &$name;
            my $new_name = 'get' . ucfirst($name);
            *{$new_name} = \&$name;
            }
        }
    }

Foo->getArea;
Foo->getLength;
Foo->getCroak;
```

To get around this, I can have a set list of method names to translate:

```
use v5.10;

package Foo {
    use Carp qw(croak);
    sub area { say "In area"; }
    sub length { say "In length"; }

    BEGIN {
        no strict 'refs';
        my @translateable = qw(area length);
        foreach my $name ( @translateable ) {
            next unless defined &$name;
            my $new_name = 'get' . ucfirst($name);
            *{$new_name} = \&$name;
            }
        }
    }

Foo->getArea;
Foo->getLength;
Foo->getCroak;
```

Now `getCroak` isn't there:

```
In area
In length
Can't locate object method "getCroak" via package "Foo"
```

But this requires that I know all those names and have them in `@translateable`. That's a hassle and it's likely I will miss some.

There's another way that I've been playing with for a few years, and it's a bit confusing until you grok it. You can do things with various Perl things at compile time by setting attributes on that thing:

```
sub area   :Alias( "getArea" )   { say "In area"; }
```

When perl sees that `:Alias` attribute on a sub definition, it calls the special method `MODIFY_CODE_ATTRIBUTES` and gives it a list of the attributes (there can be more than one). It's then up to me to do whatever you I to do.

That attribute string in `MODIFY_CODE_ATTRIBUTES` is going to be whatever I typed, from the `:` to the closing paren. I need to parse that myself. In this example, I'm going to assume I might have more than one alias, so I want to handle attributes such asa `:Alias( "getArea get_area" )` and end up with two aliases:

```
use v5.10;

package Foo {
    use Carp qw(croak);
    use B;

    sub MODIFY_CODE_ATTRIBUTES {
        my( $package, $code_ref, @attributes ) = @_;
        my( $sub_name ) = B::svref_2object( $code_ref )->GV->NAME;

        # there can be other attributes, so select the one I want
        my( $alias ) = grep { /\AAlias\(/ } @attributes;
        my( $alias_string ) = $alias =~ /\A Alias \( \s* "(.*?)" \s* \) /x;
        my @aliases = split /\s+/, $alias_string;

        foreach my $alias ( @aliases ) {
            no strict 'refs';
            *{__PACKAGE__ . '::' . $alias} = $code_ref;
            }

        return;
        }

    sub area   :Alias( "getArea" )   { say "In area"; }
    sub length :Alias( "getLength get_length" ) { say "In length"; }
    }

Foo->getArea;
Foo->getLength;
Foo->get_length;
Foo->getCroak;
```

Now `getLength` and `get_length` work, and `getCroak` still doesn't:

```
In area
In length
In length
Can't locate object method "getCroak" via package "Foo"
```

In real work, I use `MODIFY_CODE_ATTRIBUTES` to dispatch to other subs to handle individual attributes, but that's just work. The set up is a bit of a pain in the ass, but once there I tend to like it. The aliases stay right next to their target. Adding the attributes isn't so bad if you add them with another program. At some point there needs to be list of the ones you want to translate anyway. And, someone looking at the code can now search for the alias name and end up at the definition, which I think is the biggest win.

Comment: This opens up a whole new can of learning for me. Thanks for taking the time, and I will probably print this out and read it carefully over the weekend and give it a go.

Comment: And I think I will use a mixed solution: I don't think I can find out all the methods that Geo::Geos has, but I can definitely pinpoint a bunch, and use AUTOLOAD for the rest